# Blob.topdf() throws error when parameter consist of <img>

Tags: blob.topdf

Seeking some help. When Blob.topdf() has to process email.htmlbody with  tag, it throws an error as explained here. http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000123577&language=en_US

can we remove  from the email.htmlbody using replaceAll, substring, and indexOf? May be say email.htmlBody.replaceAll(from '< img src' to 'first > after < img src')?

Is there a workaround? This link has two workaround..but i need to use blob.topdf in an email service class and not vf page.

OR

Is there a way to remove the  tag which is automatically added at the end of the visualforce template?

Thank you!!

Regards,
cL

Comment: I think you might be out of luck, the toPdf function is quite limited, it doesn't respect styling and some other html. Is your process a batch/future job? Otherwise, you should be able to use a VF page.

Comment: can we remove <img src.......> from the email.htmlbody using replaceAll, substring, and indexOf?

May be say email.htmlBody.replaceAll(from '<img src' to 'first > after <img src'?

Comment: Maybe worth a try, it's actually the src attribute of the img element that it is complaining about so if you could remove that it might work. Maybe try replacing src with something else to fool it?

Comment: It seems to be working just sent out 20 emails to be processed..the pdf is also being created tip top..hoping there's no error..
However, with email.htmlbody without removing <img src=..>, almost 10 emails are processed correctly out of 20 emails..it's extremely annoying it doesn't work but it works..
Thanks for your input Phil!

Comment: What was the solution then? Might be worth answering your own question if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using passing email.htmlBody as a parameter to Blob.toPdf(), following error is thrown:
FATAL_ERROR|System.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred while parsing the input string.

This happens, because Salesforce system automatically parses  tag at the end of email to track the HTML emails. We can see this when we View Source of the email say in Outlook...

The catch is sometimes Blob.toPdf() does processes email.htmlBody correctly.

So in order to avoid this sporadic behavior of this method, we can simply remove src attribute from email.htmlBody and it should work.

email.htmlBody.replaceall('src','');